# Proofs of various integral properties

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, intuition, riemann-integration

Consider the definition of definite integral in terms of a Riemann sum, i.e. Let $[a,b]$ be some interval on the real line. We then define a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ in terms of a set of subintervals of $[a,b]$ such that $P=\lbrace [x_{0},x_{1}],\ldots ,[x_{i-1},x_{i}], \ldots ,[x_{n-1},x_{n}]\rbrace$, where $a=x_{0}<x_{1}<\cdots <x_{i-1}<x_{i}<\cdots <x_{n-1}<x_{n}=b$. The width of each subinterval is then given by $\Delta x_{i}=x_{i}-x_{i-1}$, with $\text{Max}\,\lvert\Delta x_{i}\rvert =\lbrace\lvert x_{1}-x_{0}\rvert ,\ldots ,\lvert x_{i}-x_{i-1}\rvert ,\cdots ,\lvert x_{n}-x_{n-1}\rvert\rbrace$ the maximum possible width attainable for a subinterval.
We then define the integral from $a$ to $b$ of a function $f(x)$ as follows, $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\text{Max}\,\lvert\Delta x_{i}\rvert\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i =1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\Delta x_{i}$$ where $\zeta_{i}\in [x_{i-1},x_{i}]$.

Given this definition of the definite integral, is it possible to prove the following properties: $$1.\qquad\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=-\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\ 2.\qquad\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx =0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\\ 3.\qquad\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx +\int_{b}^{c}f(x)dx$$ or are these simply taken to be defining properties (although, looking at it $2.$ seems to follow from $1.$ in the case where $a=b$)?

In some notes I've read (for example, these ones: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch11.pdf), properties $1.$ and $2.$ are simply given as definitions, whereas in other notes (for example, these ones: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ProofIntProp.aspx ) they are proven. In all cases, property $3.$ seems to be provable.

Comment: Yes, these are properties that you can prove using the definition of Riemann integral. They are quite easy to show if you use a geometric approach.

Comment: @Edu           Ah ok. For $1.$ then, can we simply rewrite the Riemann sum as $$\sum_{i =1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\left(x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right)=-\sum_{i =1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\left(x_{i-1}-x_{i}\right)$$ such that in the limit $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\text{Max}\,\lvert\Delta x_{i}\rvert\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i =1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\left( x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right)=-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\text{Max}\,\lvert\Delta x_{i}\rvert\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i =1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\left( x_{i-1}-x_{i}\right)=-\int_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$$

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with this definition of Riemann integral that you're using. The classical definition (roughly speaking) involves sums of the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $f$ on each interval of the partition (lower and upper sums). Then the function is Riemann integrable if the limit as $n\to\infty$ of the subtraction of the upper and lower sums is zero for a sequence of partitions $P_n$, and in this case the integral on $[a,b]$ is equal to any of these limits (because they are equal to each other). But again, if you think about the properties in a geometric way, it'll be easier.

Comment: @Edu           Unfortunately, I've only ever been taught from a physicists perspective in which either the definition I gave in my OP has been used, or alternatively, if one considers each of the subintervals to be of equal width then another definition I've seen is $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\Delta x$$ where $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $\zeta_{i}\in [x_{i-1},x_{i}]$. I'm not particularly familiar with the definition in terms of lower and upper sums unfortunately.

Comment: Don't worry, the definition you are using might be equivalent (at least in terms of computations). And yes, sometimes the properties in the OP are included as part of the definition. You can have a look at this [link](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtd/1/txe3da1a.htm) as it includes some geometrical explanations that may allow you to understand what is going on (and why these properties can be taken as an "extended definition").

Comment: @Edu           Thanks for the link, it is very helpful. I couple of questions on notation. By $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx =\text{inf}_{P}\lbrace U(f;P)\rbrace$$ is it meant that, given the set of upper Riemann sums for all possible partitions of the given interval $[a,b]$, the integral is equal to the smallest upper Riemann sum in the set?! Why is it necessarily true that if $f$ is Riemann integrable then $$\text{inf}_{P}\lbrace U(f;P)\rbrace =\text{sup}_{P}\lbrace L(f;P)\rbrace$$

Comment: Is it simply because if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $$L(f;P)\leq\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \leq U(f;P)$$ and so $$\text{sup}_{P}\lbrace L(f;P)\rbrace=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\text{inf}_{P}\lbrace U(f;P)\rbrace$$

Comment: No. First there is the definition: $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if its upper integral ($\inf$ of $U$ over all partitions) and lower integral ($\sup$ of $L$ over all partitions) are equal. Then, there is a characterization of integrability which states that $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if there is a sequence $(P_n)$ of partitions such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n))=0,$$ and in that case $$\int_a^b f=\lim_{n\to\infty}U(f,P_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}L(f,P_n).$$

Comment: @Edu           So what does the notation $\text{inf}_{P}\lbrace U(f;P)\rbrace$ mean? I think the definition you gave in your last comment might be equivalent to mine since, as far as I understand it $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\text{Max}\;\Delta x_{i}\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\left(x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right)$$ is a limit of a sequence of partitions (in the limit of the width of each subinterval tending to zero) ...

Comment: ... and so it seems to me that it should be the case that, in this limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\text{Max}\;\Delta x_{i}\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{i})\left(x_{i}-x_{i-1}\right) =\lim_{n\rightarrow}U(f;P_{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow}L(f;P_{n})$$ Since the value of the integral should be independent of the the points in each subinterval at which we choose to evaluate $f$.

Comment: @Edu           Also, just to clarify, does $\text{Max}\;\lvert\Delta x_{i}\rvert$ denote the maximum possible width of a subinterval? That is, is it equal to the width of the widest subinterval, and therefore, by requiring that this tends to zero, this ensures that the widths of all the subintervals will tend to zero in this limit (since no subinterval can have a width greater that $\text{Max}\;\lvert\Delta x_{i}\rvert$ by definition)?!